# Absolute element doesn't overlap fixed position div

Tags: html, css

I have layout with two fixed positioned div's(Class A and Class B). Also i have a absolute positioned div(Class C) inside class B with z-index greater than class A. In chrome class C doesn't overlap class A. It is working fine in Firefox.

#### HTML

```
<div class="A"></div>
<div class="B">
    <div class="C"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.A{position:fixed; width:200px; height:50px; z-index:1; background-color:#FCC}
.B{ position:fixed}
.C{position:absolute; z-index:2; top:-10px; background-color:#CC6; width:70px; height:50px;}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLaZj/)

Note: Adding z-index to class B might solve the problem, but in my case i cannot do that. Is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried z-index:-1 on A?

Comment: Your problem is, that you have no z-index on B which is where c is nested within. The z-index only works on the parent. Putting it on a child doesnt do anything.

Comment: Can you explain why you cant put a z-index on B??

Comment: @Isius - I need z-index on A, bcoz i have a layout wer i use only window scrollbar to scroll the contents. In that case class A will act as header and it needs to have healthy z-index value

Comment: @Cam Lets say i have a dropdown inside classA. If i add greater z-index to class B, dropdown doesnt comeup.

Comment: No, element attributes are taken from the parent class, so for instance if you said, .b {z-index }, z-index is then applied to the child elements. Now having .a as absolute not relative is why you are not seeing it.

Comment: This might help you. http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: You have not provided enough information for anyone to help you. Try expanding upon your question.

Answer (score 0):

set `z-index:0` on `.A` and it will move on top